# Github cannot commit

Tags: github, commit

I just imported a new project directory into github and it won't let me commit. This is the error:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean imported?  Did you copy the project directory to an github repo? Or are you trying to add the directory as a repo?